# Create Unusual Recurring Outlook Event: Friday Following the 15th of Every Month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, outlook-web-access

I'm using Outlook 2010. I'm ok with writing VBScript if necessary.

The event can be on the 15th if it's a Friday.

Comment: Isn't the 3rd Friday of every month going to be the Friday after the 15th (or the 15th itself)?  You can set the 3rd Friday of the month in the standard recurring appointment setup.

Comment: @techie007 Ya you're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd Friday of every month going to be the Friday after the 15th (or the 15th itself).

You can set the 3rd Friday of the month in the standard recurring appointment setup:

(Outlook 2007):

[image]